# Identification of SWD header for footprint

Tags: identification, pcb-assembly

I figure StackExchange is the fastest way to get an answer. I need a header to put up a SWD connector, looking like this (and yes one of the solder pad is missing), a part number would be appreciated!

[image]

Comment: Have you looked at the evaluation kit data sheet? Or contacted ST?

Comment: google `SWD connector`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a Tag-Connect TC-2050 footprint. There is no header. It is a headerless connector that plugs directly into the PCB. That footprint has four large holes to accommodate the "legged" version of the plug which retains the plug on the PCB. The legless version will also fit into there too but is meant for production where you just hold the connector against the PCB, program it, and then move onto the next.

You may also need their adapter to adapt the cable itself to your USB programmer. They are overpriced, but they are really good. I really like them.

You can get them direct from the manufacturer or from Digikey.

https://www.tag-connect.com/products

Follow "Solution By Debugger"

Answer (score 1):

The quickest way is actually the boards evaluation page

https://www.st.com/en/evaluation-tools/st25ru3993-eval.html

Under the databrief, it shows the interface
[image]

Later on they provide specifics of the connector interface
[image]

A quick google for **TC2050-IDC** brings us to: https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/tag-connect-llc/TC2050-IDC/TC2050-IDC-ND/2605366